# Insert data into oracle DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have a table in oracle with primary key and auto increment attribute. But sometimes I have preset ID value for the record.

So when I try to insert record I get exception your trying to insert into table with auto increment field.
So in SQLDeveloper I tried by disabling triggering and inserting values and then enabling trigger which worked perfectly

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM ARCHIVE_TABLE_NAME  WHERE TABLE_NAME_COLUMN >= '27-JUN-16 10.35.12.945000000';
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ENABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
```

But I would like to do this grammatically through hibernate.

So I have following questions

1) If is there any other way of inserting records in table with auto incremtn field?

2) If no then how to execute above 3 statements in hibernate

Answer (score 0):

you can insert records with auto increment key by using the following jpa annotation on your auto incremented field

```
    @GeneratedValue(generator="InvSeq") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name="InvSeq",sequenceName="INV_SEQ", allocationSize=5)
    private long autoIncId;
```

see this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/id-generation-083058.html

Comment: I solved it by executing above three statements independetly